# Is there anything in Rust to convert a binary string to an integer?

Tags: binary, integer, rust

My binary resides as a string right now, I was hoping to `format!` it as an integer the same way I formatted my integer to binary: `format!("{:b}", number)`.

I have a larger string of binary that I'm taking slices out of in a loop, so let's assume one of my slices is:

```
let bin_idx: &str = "01110011001";
```

I want to format that binary into an integer:

```
format!("{:i}", bin_idx);
```

This gives a compiler error:

```
error: unknown format trait `i`
 --> src/main.rs:3:21
  |
3 |     format!("{:i}", bin_idx);
  |                     ^^^^^^^
```

I also tried [`d` and `u`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/0.12.0/std/fmt/index.html) and got the same error.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

First of all, you should be using [the official docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/#formatting-traits); those you pointed to are way outdated.

You have a string and you can't format a string as an integer. I think what you want is a parser. Here's a version using `from_str_radix`:

```rust
fn main() {
    let bin_idx = "01110011001";
    let intval = isize::from_str_radix(bin_idx, 2).unwrap();
    println!("{}", intval);
}
```

([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=73e9298523d233581442631268388c0f))

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative you can use:

```
let bstr = "11010101";
let i = i32::from_str_radix(bstr, 2).expect("Not a binary number!");
println!("{i}");
```

Which should print `213`.

EDIT: Posted that answer as I thought `isize` for some reason was not available in my embedded rust project. Was just a typo though...

Answer (score 0):

I made a function up by myself, and it works!

```
fn binary_to_u32(s: String) -> u32 {
let mut binary_digit =  s.chars().count();
let mut real_num: u32 = 0;
for c in s.chars() { 
    let mut temp_var = 2u32.pow(binary_digit.try_into().unwrap());
    temp_var /= 2;
    if c == '1'{
        real_num += temp_var;
    }
    binary_digit -= 1;
}
return real_num; }
```

Also, if you have need for any other integer size, just change u32 to anything you like with some replace shortcut in your text editor.

Comment: Why would you use this instead of the one in the standard library that is thoroughly tested?

Comment: 1. It suits all integer type in rust     2. I thought it is easier to write this simple function myself than look for thing that could be non-existing.

Comment: *It suits all integer type* — [as does the existing answer](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/?search=from_str_radix).

Comment: I did not knew that. Thank you! Maybe I am bad at Google-ing because I did not find it.

Comment: also this version has suboptimal performance with pow and division in a loop. Instead multiplication and addition would be much better.